# Creating a dataframe based on multiple columns of a data.frame or data.table

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like this:

```
      V1    V2          V3    V4
  4: ASW NA19704-200-37 SVLEN  0
  5: ASW NA19834-200-37 SVLEN  0                          
301: YRI    GS000017413 SVLEN  0
302: YRI    GS000017898 SVLEN  0
303: YRI    GS000018623 SVLEN  0
```

I also have this in a data frame. I want to sum V4 for all columns in which V1 AND V3 have the same values.

V1 has 5 values, and V3 has 24, all of which are strings, but I can convert them to factors or whatever else.

The statement:

```
chr10pos53400000dt[chr10pos53400000dt$V3=="CDS",sum(V4),by=V1]
```

Returns:

```
      V1  V1
1:   ASW   9
2:   CEU  68
3: Lupus 109
4:    RA 160
5:   YRI 163
```

Which is what it should return.

Only now, I wish to do this for ALL values in V3. To do this I made a vector called "ComponentList" via the command `ComponentList=unique(chr10pos53400000dt$V3)`.

The statement `for (i in ComponentList) {ByComponent[i]<-chr10pos53400000dt[chr10pos53400000dt$V3==ComponentList[i],sum(V4),by=V1]}` issues 24 error messages (same as the length of `ComponentList`) saying

```
24: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = structure(list( ... :
provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Does anyone know how I can fill a new data frame with the results like those above, but iteratively??

Thank you very much!

Comment: I must be confused what you want...can't you just sum v4 with ```chr10pos53400000dt[,sum(V4),by=c("V1",V2","V3")]```?

Comment: Ugh it was this easy. I read a lot of the man for data.table I must have just missed that you can use by to key more than one thing. I thought I remembered it saying you can only index on one column.

This worked like a charm and has the intended effect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want this:

```
chr10pos53400000dt[, sum(V4), by=list(V3, V1)]
```